# Turning on the GPS on android 4.4

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to get GPS Longitude & Latitude.
Everything is working in case that the GPS is turning on while using any other program that turning it on.

But when i trying to use only my app , the GPS is not turning on.

here is my code:

```
 m_locationManager = (LocationManager)  getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


String provider = m_locationManager.getBestProvider(m_c, false);
Location location = m_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if (location != null)
{
double lng = location.getLongitude();
double lat = location.getLatitude();
gpsLocationLon.setText("" + lng);
gpsLocationLat.setText("" + lat);
}
else
{
gpsLocationLon.setText("No Provider");
gpsLocationLat.setText("No Provider");
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        if(null != gpsLocationLat && null != gpsLocationLon)
        {
        gpsLocationLon.setText("" + lng);
        gpsLocationLon.setText("" + lat);
        }

    }
```

what did i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start listening to location updates once you've found the best provider.

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
    // ^^ This will start listening for location updates 
    // depending on your provider. 
} else {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, provider + " not enabled");
}
```

Remember that there are two types of providers, gps and network. So it depends on the criteria(`m_c`) which one is selected.

If you want to make sure that you want to listen to GPS as well as Network Updates, remove the Criteria variable and try this :

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
} else {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "network provider not enabled");
}

if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
} else {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, gps provider not enabled");
}
```

Edit 1:

```
m_locationManager = (LocationManager)  getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (m_locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    Location location = m_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}
else {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "network provider not enabled");
}
if (m_locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
else {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "gps provider not enabled");
}
if (location != null)
{
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    gpsLocationLon.setText("" + lng);
    gpsLocationLat.setText("" + lat);
}
else
{
    gpsLocationLon.setText("No Provider");
    gpsLocationLat.setText("No Provider");
}
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    if(null != gpsLocationLat && null != gpsLocationLon)
    {
        gpsLocationLon.setText("" + lng);
        gpsLocationLon.setText("" + lat);
    }
}
```

Comment: after i did set the listener for the Network updates and the GPS, how should i get the provider for the location? in case of removing the m_c

Comment: which provider do you want to use ? Network/GPS/Both ?

Comment: i would like to use both

Comment: I've mentioned how to use both the providers above. Get rid of the criteria variable to get the best provider. To get the last known location you can use network.

Comment: getBestProvider accepting only 2 variable , there is not an overloading for only Boolean..

Comment: You dont need to use getBestProvider(). Check Edit 1 in the answer.